# Android: Is There a way to stream video on a app?

Tags: android

I've seen apps like netflix that stream video.  Is there a way to do this using the sdk? I could not find anything about how to stream on android.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple example of a `VideoView` streaming a file

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {

String url = "http://yourvideo/url/video.mp4";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
       myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
       myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
       myVideoView.requestFocus();
       myVideoView.start();
   }
}
```

And in your XML somewhere:

```
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: This may not work sometime. Pls, refer  https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/android-development-play-youtube-video-in-your-app-cant-play-this-video-and-troubleshooting/   The post suggests using Google API for youtube videos. I am not sure if that can be used to stream video from your own server.

Comment: You may have to implement RTSP or RTMP for streaming from your server.