# How can I stream videos from a server to an Android app?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

My local church hosts a weekly show and upload the videos on Youtube. And I've been asked to develop an app for them, so far all is well, however, I have to implement a feature that will allow me to stream the show's videos unto the app.

I honestly don't have much of a clue how to go about it (still new to android programming)! I've looked around here and seen that a few people have already attempted to do this, but unlike what most people have done or tried to do, the videos are released on that day (not live streaming). For example the `10/02/13` video will be released on `10/02/13`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262094/android-is-there-a-way-to-stream-video-on-a-app) link gives me an idea on how to stream a video on Android, but that shows that I have to explicitly put in the link for the video.

Is there a way to do the same thing, but instead of adding the link myself, the app should retrieve the videos from a server??

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the link but instead of adding the link myself, the app should retrieve the videos from a server??

To achieve this you need to make the ***webservice*** which help to communicate mobile and web server. When you send the request from mobile to server then make the web service which give you response which have link of video then you can stream the video.

To stream the video.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262094/android-is-there-a-way-to-stream-video-on-a-app).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about the web service. But on the link you gave me, they person has explicitly inserted the link for the video.....Is there a way of doing that but without explicitly inserting the link myself?

Comment: this answer really helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Inside the API DEMOS you have on example.

API DEMOS >> Media >> Mediaplayer >> Play Streaming Video

You need to downloaded using the SDK Manager, and then inside eclipse you go throw create new project form existing sample, then you read the code and copy it inside your app.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "...go throw create new project form existing sample..." DO you mean that I should create a new project from the existing sample??

Comment: Only to see the code, and to know how can you do the streaming of a video. After you create the project, you can put it on your device, and then search in the list Media, Mediaplay, and streaming. Then, inside eclipse you will be able to see the code...